# Find the constants $a,b,c$ such that the directional derivative is maximum on the direction of $\vec{u}$

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as $f(x,y,z)=ax^2y+by^2 z+cz^2 x$. Find the constants $a,b,c$ such that in the point $(1,1,1)$, the directional derivative is maximum in the direction $\hat{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}(1,5,0)$ and equals $13$.

So I know that the gradient can be found $\vec{\nabla f (1,1,1)}=(2a+c,2b+a,2c+b)$, and then I know since it is a differentiable function that: $$f'_{u}(1,1,1)=13=\vec{\nabla f(1,1,1)}\cdot \hat{u}\Rightarrow 13=(2a+c,2b+a,2c+b)\cdot (1,5,0)\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}$$ but then I have an equation with 3 variables and I don't know how to continue. Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: Hint : Develop the scalar product in last equality, then you can determine  your answer.

Comment: @EDX but then I get to $13=\frac{7a+10b+c}{\sqrt{26}}$? How can I determine my answer from here?

Comment: If you havent further informations, your solution are the $(a,b,c)$ such that they satistify the equality you've just written.

Comment: @EDX the solution of the book does find numeric values for all $a,b,c$ though?